# Read a Word template in Java and write other info

Tags: java, templates, ms-word

I have to read a .doc or a .docx document with some static fields like title, header with a program written in Java.
With the same program a user fills a form (GUI) and all these infos should be added in the right place in the document previously read.

Which framework is most suitable for my work?

Comment: What about [`Apache POI - the Java API for Microsoft Documents`](http://poi.apache.org/)?

Comment: if there's the possibility to read a document previously built and then add other info  it's perfect for my purpose . thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17693553/how-to-insert-data-into-a-microsoft-word-template-using-java/17716451#17716451

Answer (score 0):

See [apache-poi-or-docx4j-for-dealing-with-docx-documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15013837/apache-poi-or-docx4j-for-dealing-with-docx-documents)

For techniques relating to adding text into a document, see [document-generation](http://www.slideshare.net/plutext/document-generation-2012osdcsydney)

docx4j works mainly with docx (and pptx, xlsx) files.  As far as legacy binary docs are concerned, you have a couple of options:

- use POI's HWPF support.  This is included in docx4j as a dependency.  But its not a great approach, since it doesn't convert the doc to docx4j's internal representation:- you're kinda stuck in HWPF land
- use JODConverter to convert the doc to a docx, and if necessary, back again.  This is the best way to go.